# Java String Index out of range error, don't know why

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a program for a school project that reads a chemical formula and determines mass and percent composition. I am trying to write the method to read the formula and create an array containing symbols based upon how often that element shows up in a formula. However, whenever I test the formula reader method, I get an string index out of range error. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
//http://www.ptable.com/ was the source for information on elements
//knowledgedoor.com/ was the source for charges of elements not listed on common ion sheet and not having a charge based on what group it was. I used the one that said more common. Did not use if said with disagreement
// If an element had multiple charges from common ion sheet, I created multiple objects with similar attributes except charge. Object was named using atomic symbol and a number following corresponding to roman numeral




import java.util.Scanner;
public class compositionMassMolesAtoms {
public static double avoNum = (6.02 * Math.pow(10,23));
static Element H = new Element(1,1,1, "Hydrogen", "H", 1.007, 1, "nonmetal");
static Element He = new Element(1,18,2, "Helium", "He", 4.002, 0, "nonmetal");
static Element Li = new Element(2,1,3,"Lithium", "Li", 6.941, 1, "metal");
//period 2
 static Element Be = new Element(2,2,4,"Beryllium", "Be", 9.012, 2, "metal");
static Element B = new Element(2,13,5, "Boron", "B", 10.811, 3, "metalloid");
static Element C = new Element(2,14,6, "Carbon", "C", 12.0107, 4, "metal");
static Element N = new Element(2,15,7, "Nitrogen", "N", 14.007, -3, "nonmetal");
static Element O = new Element(2,16,8, "Oxygen", "O", 15.9994, -2, "nonmetal");
static Element F = new Element(2,17,9, "Fluorine", "F", 18.998,  -1, "nonmetal");
static Element Ne = new Element(2,18,10, "Neon", "Ne", 20.1797, 0, "nonmetal");
   // period 3
static Element Na = new Element(3,1,11, "Sodium", "Na", 22.989, 1, "metal");
static Element Mg = new Element(3,2,12, "Magnesium", "Mg", 24.305, 2, "metal");
static Element Al = new Element(3,13,13, "Aluminum", "Al", 26.981, 3, "metals");
static Element Si = new Element(3,14,14, "Silicon", "Si", 28.085, 4, "metalloid");
static Element P = new Element(3,15,15, "Phosphorous", "P",  30.973, -3, "nonmetal");
static Element S = new Element(3,16,16, "Sulfur", "S", 32.06, -2, "nonmetal");
static Element Cl = new Element(3,17,17, "Chlorine", "Cl", 35.45, -1, "nonmetal");
static Element Ar = new Element(3,18,18, "Argon", "Ar", 39.948, 0, "nonmetal");
   //period 4
static Element K = new Element(4,1,19, "Potassium", "K", 39.0983, 1, "metal");    
static Element Ca = new Element(4,2,20, "Calcium", "Ca", 40.078, 2, "metal");
static Element Sc = new Element(4,3,21, "Scandium", "Sc", 44.955, 3, "metal");
static Element Ti = new Element(4,4,22, "Titanium", "Ti", 47.867, 4, "metal");
static Element V = new Element(4,5,23, "Vanadium", "V", 50.9415, 5, "metal");
static Element Cr2 = new Element(4,6,24, "Chromium", "Cr", 51.9961, 2, "metal");
static Element Cr3 = new Element(4,6,24, "Chromium", "Cr", 51.9961, 3, "metal");
static Element Mn2 = new Element(4,7,25, "Manganese", "Mn", 54.938, 2, "metal");
static Element Mn3 = new Element(4,7,25, "Manganese", "Mn", 54.938, 3, "metal");
static Element Mn4 = new Element(4,7,25, "Manganese", "Mn", 54.938, 4, "metal");
static Element Fe2 = new Element(4,8,26, "Iron", "Fe", 55.845, 2, "metal");
static Element Fe3 = new Element(4,8,26, "Iron", "Fe", 55.845, 3, "metal");
static Element Co2 = new Element(4,9,27, "Cobalt", "Co", 58.933, 2, "metal");
static Element Co3 = new Element(4,9,27, "Cobalt", "Co", 58.933, 3, "metal");
static Element Ni2 = new Element(4,10,28, "Nickel", "Ni", 58.6934, 2, "metal");
static Element Ni3 = new Element(4,10,28, "Nickel", "Ni", 58.6934, 3, "metal");
static Element Cu1 = new Element(4,11,29, "Copper", "Cu", 63.546, 1, "metal");
static Element Cu2 = new Element(4,11,29, "Copper", "Cu", 63.546, 2, "metal");
static Element Zn = new Element(4,12,30, "Zinc", "Zn", 65.38, 2, "metal");
static Element Ga = new Element(4,13,31, "Gallium", "Ga", 69.723, 3, "metal");
static Element Ge = new Element(4,14,32, "Germanium", "Ge", 72.63, 4, "metalloid");
static Element As = new Element(4,15,33, "Arsenic", "As", 74.9216, -3, "metalloid");
static Element Se = new Element(4,16,34, "Selenium", "Se", 78.96, -2, "nonmetal");
static Element Br = new Element(4,17,35, "Bromine", "Br", 79.904, -1, "nonmetal");
static Element Kr = new Element(4,18,36, "Krypton", "Kr", 83.798, 0, "nonmetal");
   //period 5
static Element Rb = new Element(5,1,37, "Rubidium", "Rb", 85.4678, 1, "metal");  
static Element Sr = new Element(5,2,38, "Strontium", "Sr", 87.62, 2, "metal");
static Element Y = new Element(5,3,39, "Yttrium", "Y", 88.90585, 3, "metal");
static Element Zr = new Element(5,4,40, "Zirconium", "Zr", 91.224, 4, "metal");
static Element Nb = new Element(5,5,41, "Niobium", "Nb", 92.90638, 5, "metal");
static Element Mo = new Element(5,6,42, "Molybdenum", "Mo", 95.96, 6, "metal");
static Element Tc = new Element(5,7,43, "Technetium", "Tc", 98, 4, "metal");
static Element Ru = new Element(5,8,44, "Ruthenium", "Ru", 101.07, 3, "metal");
static Element Rh = new Element(5,9,45, "Rhodium", "Rh", 102.90550, 3, "metal");
static Element Pd = new Element(5,10,46, "Palladium", "Pd", 106.43, 2, "metal");
static Element Ag = new Element(5,11,47, "Silver", "Ag", 107.8682, 1, "metal");

   // charges after this point are not accurate, as they are just set to one.
   // need to go back and correct charges

static Element Cd = new Element(5,12,48, "Cadmium", "Cd", 112.411, 1, "metal");
static Element In = new Element(5,13,49, "Indium", "In", 114.818, 1, "metal");
static Element Sn = new Element(5,14,50, "Tin", "Sn", 118.710, 1, "metal");
static Element Sb = new Element(5,15,51, "Antimony", "Sb", 121.760, 1,"metalloid");
static Element Te = new Element(5,16,52, "Tellurium", "Te", 127.60, 1, "metalloid");
static Element I = new Element(5,17,53, "Iodine", "I", 126.90, 1, "nonmetal");
static Element Xe = new Element(5,18,54, "Xenon", "Xe", 131.293, 1, "nonmetal");
   // period 6
static Element Cs = new Element(6,1,55, "Caesium", "Cs", 132.90, 1, "metal");
static Element Ba = new Element(6,2,56, "Barium", "Ba", 137.327, 1, "metal");
   // Lanthanoids
static Element La = new Element(8,1,57, "Lanthanum", "La", 138.90, 1, "metal");
static Element Ce = new Element(8,2,58, "Cerium", "Ce", 140.116, 1, "metal");
static Element Pr = new Element(8,3,59, "Praseodymium", "Pr", 140.90, 1, "metal");
static Element Nd = new Element(8,4,60, "Neodymium", "Nd", 144.242, 1, "metal");
static Element Pm = new Element(8,5,61, "Promethium", "Pm", 145, 1, "metal");
static Element Sm = new Element(8,6,62, "Samarium", "Sm", 150.36, 1, "metal");
static Element Eu = new Element(8,7,63, "Europium", "Eu", 151.964, 1, "metal");
static Element Gd = new Element(8,8,64, "Gadolinium", "Gd", 157.25, 1, "metal");
static Element Tb = new Element(8,9,65, "Terbium", "Tb", 158.92, 1, "metal");
static Element Dy = new Element(8,10,66, "Dysprosium", "Dy", 162.5, 1, "metal");
static Element Ho = new Element(8,11,67, "Holmium", "Ho", 164.93, 1, "metal");
static Element Er = new Element(8,12,68, "Erbium", "Er", 167.259, 1, "metal");
static Element Tm = new Element(8,13,69, "Thulium", "Tm", 168.93, 1, "metal");
static Element Yb = new Element(8,14,70, "Ytterbium", "Yb", 173.054, 1, "metal");
static Element Lu = new Element(8,15,71, "Lutetium", "Lu", 174.9668, 1, "metal");
   // End of lanthanoids, period 6
static Element Hf = new Element(6,4,72, "Hafnium", "Hf", 178.49, 1, "metal");
static Element Ta = new Element(6,5,73, "Tantalum", "Ta", 180.94, 1, "metal");
static Element W = new Element(6,6,74, "Tungsten", "W", 183.84, 1, "metal");
static Element Re = new Element(6,7,75, "Rhenium", "Re", 186.207, 1, "metal");
static Element Os = new Element(6,8,76,"Osmium", "Os", 190.23, 1, "metal"); 
static Element Ir = new Element(6,9,77, "Iridium", "Ir", 192.217, 1, "metal");
static Element Pt = new Element(6,10,78, "Platinum", "Pt", 195.084, 1, "metal");
static Element Au = new Element(6,11,79, "Gold", "Au", 196.96,1,"metal");
static Element Hg = new Element(6,12,80,"Mercury", "Hg", 200.59, 1, "metal");
static Element Tl = new Element(6,13,81, "Thallium", "Tl", 204.38, 1, "metal");
static Element Pb = new Element(6,14,82, "Lead", "Pb", 207.2, 1, "metal");
static Element Bi = new Element(6,15,83, "Bismuth", "Bi", 208.98, 1, "metal");

   // most elements after this point have unconfirmed mass do to instable isotopes
   // doesn’t include uranium, does include Technetium, Thorium, Protactinium and Promethium

static Element Po = new Element(6,16,84, "Polonium", "Po", 209, 1, "metalloid");
static Element At = new Element(6,17,85, "Astatine", "At", 210, 1, "nonmetal");
static Element Rn = new Element(6,18,86, "Radon", "Rn", 222, 1, "nonmetal");
   // Period 7
static Element Fr = new Element(7,1,87, "Francium", "Fr",  223, 1, "metal");
static Element Ra = new Element(7,2,88, "Radium", "Ra", 226, 1, "metal");
   // Beginning of Actinoids
static Element Ac = new Element(9,1,89, "Actinium", "Ac", 227, 1, "metal");
static Element Th = new Element(9,2,90, "Thorium", "Th", 232.03,1, "metal");
static Element Pa = new Element(9,3,91, "Protactinium", "Pa", 231.03, 1, "metal");
static Element U = new Element(9,4,92, "Uranium", "U", 238.02, 1, "metal");
static Element Np = new Element(9,5,93, "Neptunium", "Np", 237, 1, "metal");
static Element Pu = new Element(9,6,94, "Plutonium", "Pu", 244, 1, "metal");
static Element Am = new Element(9,7,95, "Americium", "Am", 243, 1, "metal");
static Element Cm = new Element(9,8,96, "Curium", "Cm", 247, 1, "metal");
static Element Bk = new Element(9,9,97, "Berkelium", "Bk", 247, 1, "metal");
static Element Cf = new Element(9,10,98, "Californium", "Cf", 251, 1, "metal");
static Element Es = new Element(9,11,99, "Einsteinium", "Es", 252, 1, "metal");
static Element Fm = new Element(9,12,100, "Fermium", "Fm", 257, 1, "metal");
static Element Md = new Element(9,13,101, "Mendelevium", "Md",  258, 1, "metal");
static Element No = new Element(9,14,102, "Nobelium", "No", 259, 1, "metal");
static Element Lr = new Element(9,15, 103, "Lawrencium", "Lr", 262,1,"metal");
   // Actinoids finished. Not going to do element with an unknown state as of 1/26/17 


 public static double getMass(String sym) {
    if (sym.equals("H")) {
       return H.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("He")) {
       return He.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Li")) {
       return Li.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Be")) {
       return Be.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("B")) {
       return B.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("C")) {
       return C.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("N")) {
       return N.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("O")) {
       return O.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("F")) {
       return F.mass;   
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ne")) {
       return Ne.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Na")) {
       return Na.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Mg")) {
       return Mg.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Al")) {
        return Al.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Si")) {
        return Si.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("P")) {
        return P.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("S")) {
        return Si.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Cl")) {
        return Cl.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ar")) {
        return Ar.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("K")) {
        return K.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ca")) {
        return Ca.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Sc")) {
        return Sc.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ti")) {
        return Ti.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("V")) {
        return V.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Cr")) {
        return Cr2.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Mn")) {
        return Mn2.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Fe")) {
        return Fe2.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Co")) {
        return Co2.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ni")) {
        return Ni2.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Cu")) {
        return Cu2.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Zn")) {
        return Zn.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ga")) {
        return Ga.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ge")) {
        return Ge.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("As")) {
       return As.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Se")) {
        return Se.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Br")) {
        return Br.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Kr")) {
        return Kr.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Rb")) {
        return Rb.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Sr")) {
        return Sr.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Y")) {
        return Y.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Zr")) {
        return Zr.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Nb")) {
        return Nb.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Mo")) {
        return Mo.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Tc")) {
        return Tc.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ru")) {
        return Ru.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Rh")) {
        return Rh.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Pd")) {
        return Pd.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ag")) {
        return Ag.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Cd")) {
        return Cd.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("In")) {
        return In.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Sn")) {
        return Sn.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Sb")) {
        return Sb.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Te")) {
        return Te.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("I")) {
        return I.mass;
    } 
    else if(sym.equals("Xe")) {
        return Xe.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Cs")) {
        return Cs.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ba")) {
        return Ba.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("La")) {
        return La.mass;
    } 
    else if(sym.equals("Ce")) {
        return Ce.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Pr")) {
        return Pr.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Nd")) {
        return Nd.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Pm")) {
        return Pm.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Sm")) {
        return Sm.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Eu")) {
        return Eu.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Gd")) {
        return Gd.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Tb")) {
        return Tb.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Dy")) {
        return Dy.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ho")) {
        return Ho.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Er")) {
        return Er.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Tm")) {
        return Tm.mass;
    }       
    else if(sym.equals("Yb")) {
        return Yb.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Lu")) {
        return Si.mass;
    } 
    else if(sym.equals("Hf")) {
        return Hf.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ta")) {
        return Ta.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("W")) {
        return W.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Re")) {
        return Re.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Os")) {
        return Os.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ir")) {
        return Ir.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Pt")) {
        return Pt.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Au")) {
        return Au.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Hg")) {
        return Hg.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Tl")) {
        return Tl.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Pb")) {
        return Pb.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Bi")) {
        return Bi.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Po")) {
        return Po.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("At")) {
        return At.mass;
    } 
    else if(sym.equals("Rn")) {
        return Rn.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Fr")) {
        return Fr.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ra")) {
        return Ra.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Ac")) {
        return Ac.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Th")) {
        return Th.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Pa")) {
        return Pa.mass;
    } 
    else if(sym.equals("U")) {
        return U.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Np")) {
        return Np.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Pu")) {
        return Pu.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Am")) {
        return Am.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Cm")) {
        return Cm.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Bk")) {
        return Bk.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Cf")) {
        return Cf.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Es")) {
        return Es.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Fm")) {
        return Fm.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Md")) {
        return Md.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("No")) {
        return No.mass;
    }
    else if(sym.equals("Lr")) {
        return Lr.mass;
    }

    return 50000;
}
public static String[] readChemForm(String chemForm) {
    int lC = 0;
    int arrCou = 0;

    String[] elements = new String[10000];

    while(lC < chemForm.length()) {
        int elemCoun = 0;
        int jut = chemForm.length()-lC;
        if (jut > 3) {
             jut = 3;                
        }
        else{}
        Boolean lengthCheck3 = true;
        Boolean lengthCheck2 = true;
        Boolean lengthCheck1 = true;
        if (jut == 2) { 
            lengthCheck3 = false; }
        else if(jut == 1) {
            lengthCheck2 = false;
            lengthCheck3 = true;
        }
        else if(jut <= 0) {
            break; 
        }
        else {}
        String massCompF = chemForm.substring(lC,(lC+jut));  
        System.out.println(jut);
         if ((massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)).toLowerCase().equals(massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)))) && (massCompF.length() > 2)) {
             if ((massCompF.length() > 3) && (massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("2") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("3") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("4") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("5") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("6") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("7") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("8") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("9") ||massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("10") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("11") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("12") ||massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("13") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("14") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("15") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("16") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("17") ||  massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("18") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("19") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("20") || massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3)).toLowerCase().equals("21"))) {
                 String placeHolder = massCompF.substring((lC+2),(lC+3));
                 if (placeHolder.equals("2")) {
                    elemCoun = 2;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("3")) {
                    elemCoun = 3; 
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("4")) {
                    elemCoun = 4;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("5")) {
                    elemCoun = 5;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("6")) {
                    elemCoun = 6;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("7")) {
                    elemCoun = 7;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("8")) {
                     elemCoun = 8;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("10")) {
                     elemCoun = 10;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("11")) {
                     elemCoun = 11;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("12")) {
                     elemCoun = 12;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("13")) {
                     elemCoun = 13;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("14")) {
                     elemCoun = 14;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("15")) {
                     elemCoun = 15;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("15")) {
                    elemCoun = 15;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("16")) {
                     elemCoun = 16;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("17")) {
                     elemCoun = 17;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("18")) {
                     elemCoun = 18;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("19")) {
                     elemCoun = 19;
                 } 
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("20")) {
                     elemCoun = 20;
                 }
                 else if (placeHolder.equals("21")) {
                     elemCoun = 21;
                 }
                 else{}
                 String sym = massCompF.substring((lC),(lC+2));
                 for (int i = 0; i <= elemCoun; i++) {
                    elements[arrCou] = sym;
                 }
                 lC += 3;
              }
              else{
                String sym = massCompF.substring((lC),(lC+2));
                elements[arrCou] = sym;
                lC += 2;
             }
         }
         else if((!(massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)).toLowerCase().equals(massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2))))) && (massCompF.length() > 1)) {
            if ((massCompF.length() > 2) && (massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)).toLowerCase().equals("2") || massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)).toLowerCase().equals("3") || massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)).toLowerCase().equals("4") || massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)).toLowerCase().equals("5") || massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)).toLowerCase().equals("6") || massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)).toLowerCase().equals("7") || massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)).toLowerCase().equals("8") || massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)).toLowerCase().equals("9"))){
                String placeHolder = massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2));
                if (placeHolder.equals("2")) {
                   elemCoun = 2;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("3")) {
                   elemCoun = 3; 
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("4")) {
                    elemCoun = 4;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("5")) {
                    elemCoun = 5;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("6")) {
                    elemCoun = 6;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("7")) {
                    elemCoun = 7;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("8")) {
                    elemCoun = 8;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("10")) {
                    elemCoun = 10;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("11")) {
                    elemCoun = 11;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("12")) {
                    elemCoun = 12;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("13")) {
                    elemCoun = 13;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("14")) {
                    elemCoun = 14;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("15")) {
                    elemCoun = 15;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("15")) {
                    elemCoun = 15;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("16")) {
                    elemCoun = 16;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("17")) {
                    elemCoun = 17;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("18")) {
                    elemCoun = 18;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("19")) {
                    elemCoun = 19;
                } 
                else if (placeHolder.equals("20")) {
                    elemCoun = 20;
                }
                else if (placeHolder.equals("21")) {
                    elemCoun = 21;
                }
                else{}
                String sym = massCompF.substring((lC),(lC+1));
                for (int i = 0; i <= elemCoun; i++) {
                    elements[arrCou] = sym;
                }
                lC += 2;
            }
            else{}
            String sym = massCompF.substring((lC),(lC+1));
            for (int i = 0; i <= elemCoun; i++) {
                 elements[arrCou] = sym;
            }
            lC++;
        }
     } 
    return elements;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean quit = false;
    String error = "You input something that doesn't exist. Or, I forgot an element. /n Email me at rohanrtkurup@gmail.com if you find the element you input on the periodic table and you got this error.";

    while(quit == false) {
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello");
        System.out.println("What program do you want to run?");
        System.out.println("0: end program, 1: Gram to Gram 2:moles to moles, 3:Find mass and element composition"); 
        int pr1 = n.nextInt();

         switch(pr1) {
           case 3:            
           System.out.println("What is the Chemical Formula");
           String chemForm = n.next();
           String[] elements = readChemForm(chemForm);

           double totalMass = 0.0;
           int lt = 0;
           while (lt < elements.length) {
                totalMass += getMass(elements[lt]);
                lt++;
           }
           System.out.println("The total mass of that compound is: " + totalMass);
           break;
           default:
           System.out.println("");
        }
        for(int f = 0; f <= 5; f++) {  
           System.out.println("");
        }
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: You should realy use switch/case ... your code is not readable ..

Comment: It would be very kind of you if you told us which line the exception occurs in

Comment: Where is the error (i.e. what line?)  You've got a ton of code for us to go through without some more information.

Comment: You should really use a `Map`.

Comment: What is a Map? I don't know what that is.

Comment: Sorry. Error appears at line 483.

Comment: While not an answer to the question, might I suggest using enumerations for your periodic table and regular expressions to parse your formula. For example, this regex will give each element symbol and count `(([A-Z][a-z]?)([0-9]*))` assuming you are using simple non-ionic chemical formulae such as `C15H15NO2S` or `TiO2`.

Comment: Ok. I don't know how a regular expression works, and I will use Ionic formulas

Answer (score 0):

You have several loops like the following, in the loop arrCou never changes and is always 0. And sym doesn't change either for that matter. Seems not right to me.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= elemCoun; i++) {
      elements[arrCou] = sym;
}
```

And in following code, the loop goes through the entire size of elements instead of those with actual assigned values (only first slot would have anything). Seems not right either.

```
while (lt < elements.length) {
    totalMass += getMass(elements[lt]);
    lt++;
}
```

Comment: as a side topic, you probably should create a dict to store the elements and just do a lookup to retrieve the element's info instead of the numerous tests.

Comment: I am kinda new to Java. What is a dict, how do I create one, and how do I do a lookup?

Comment: for the first point, sym is not supossed to change. Elemcount is how many times that element shows up there, in order to accept subscripts. arrCou is supposed to changed, thank you for telling me.                                                                                                                                                                        For the second point, how can I make the computer to not add array elements that are not assigned?

Comment: @Firespear probably it's better to use a hashmap (basically same). here's a doc page. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: @Firespear then you only need to store elemcount and sym somewhere instead of storing sym elemcount times, for example, in a structure with two members, say, elemcount for elemcount and sym for sym.

Comment: By structure, do you mean a class constructor?

Comment: @Firespear actually i was thinking a C struct without realizing here we were talking about Java.  though you could easily create a class to function like C struct, here you only need to create two class members, say, int count and String symbol.  Then you only need to assign elemCoun to count and sym to symbol in place of that loop. then you only need to do totalMass = count * getMass(symbol) to get the total mass.

Comment: What is a C struct? I don't know any language besides java.

Comment: @Firespear you don't need something like a C struct. you only need to add two class members to hold elemCoun and sym.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I tested your code and duplicated your problem (and uncovered some other problems). To fix this index out range error, you need to put the following code as the first test in those if tests to short circuit the rest of tests in the if statement if this condition is not met.

```
(massCompF.length() > #)
```

For example, in the following code, (massCompF.length() > 2) is at the end of the test. But if massCompF.length() is not greater than 2 , this piece of code (massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)) would give you index out range error. If you move (massCompF.length() > 2) to the begin, then it will be tested first and if it's not true, the rest of tests will be skipped, so you wouldn't get the error.

```
if ((massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)).toLowerCase().equals(massCompF.substring((lC+1),(lC+2)))) &&
   (massCompF.length() > 2)) {
  ...
}
```

Another problem I found (you can duplicate it by entering H as element, after you fixed the above error) is that your following loop may go endless because in your codes, lC is not guaranteed to increase.

```
while(lC < chemForm.length()) {
 ...
}
```

Of course I can see your codes are not finished yet. Here I just pointed out what I happened to find out.

Comment: i created this new post because it directly addressed the problem and i didn't want to put too much editing in my first post.

Comment: for your first point, I'm afraid I don't understand. What does the # represent and where does that code go. For your second point, in what situation does LC not increase?

Comment: @Firespear that piece of code occurred at a few places in your codes and # in my post means a number in that piece of code, but the number is different in those different cases, so i used # instead of a real number. you have several if statements containing that piece of code, some are actually at the begin of the statement, but some are at the end. you need to move them to the begin.

Comment: @Firespear i edited the post to give you some some explanation.